# Kreisel before Kleene

Tags: biblatex, sorting

For some reason Georg Kreisel is listed before Stephen Kleene in my bibliography. I use

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authoryear,sorting=nty]{biblatex}
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}%To remove "In:" in front of journals etc, in bibliography.
\addbibresource{LIBCLASS.bib}.
```

Is there an obvious way to sort this out, or do I need the method of elimination?

Here are the entries in question:

```
@book{Kleene1952, 
  author = {Kleene, S.~C.}, 
  title = {Mathematical Logic}, 
  date = {1952}, 
  OPTeditor = {editor}, 
  OPTeditora = {editora}, 
  OPTeditorb = {editorb}, 
  OPTeditorc = {editorc}, 
  OPTtranslator = {translator}, 
  OPTannotator = {annotator}, 
  OPTcommentator = {commentator}, 
  OPTintroduction = {introduction}, 
  OPTforeword = {foreword}, 
  OPTafterword = {afterword}, 
  OPTsubtitle = {subtitle}, 
  OPTtitleaddon = {titleaddon}, 
  OPTmaintitle = {maintitle}, 
  OPTmainsubtitle = {mainsubtitle}, 
  OPTmaintitleaddon = {maintitleaddon},
  OPTlanguage = {language}, 
  OPToriglanguage = {origlanguage}, 
  OPTvolume = {volume}, 
  OPTpart = {part}, 
  OPTedition = {edition}, 
  OPTvolumes = {volumes}, 
  OPTseries = {series}, 
  OPTnumber = {number}, 
  OPTnote = {note}, 
  publisher = {North-Holland Publishing Company}, 
  OPTlocation = {location}, 
  OPTisbn = {isbn}, 
  OPTchapter = {chapter}, 
  OPTpages = {pages}, 
  OPTpagetotal = {pagetotal}, 
  OPTaddendum = {addendum}, 
  OPTpubstate = {pubstate}, 
  OPTdoi = {doi}, 
  OPTeprint = {eprint}, 
  OPTeprintclass = {eprintclass}, 
  OPTeprinttype = {eprinttype},
  OPTurl = {url}, 
  OPTurldate = {urldate},
}
@Article{Kreisel1963a, 
  author = {Kreisel, G.}, 
  title = {Subformula Prop. and Reflection Principles}, 
  journal = {J. Symb. Log.}, 
  year = {1963}, 
  key = {key}, 
  volume = {28}, 
  OPTnumber = {4}, 
  pages = {305-306}, 
  OPTmonth = {month}, 
  note = {Abstract for 28th Annual Meeting of Assoc. for Symbolic Logic}, 
  OPTannote = {annote},
}
@Article{Kreisel1963b, 
  author = {Kreisel, G.}, 
  title = {Reflection Principle for {H}eyting's arithmetic}, 
  journal = {J. Symb. Log.}, 
  year = {1963}, 
  key = {key}, 
  volume = {28}, 
  OPTnumber = {4}, 
  pages = {306-307}, 
  OPTmonth = {month}, 
  note = {Abstract for 28th Annual Meeting of Assoc. for Symbolic Logic}, 
  OPTannote = {annote},
}
@Article{Kreisel1963c, 
  author = {Kreisel, G.}, 
  title = {Reflection Principles and Omega-inconsistency}, 
  journal = {J. Symb. Log.}, 
  year = {1963}, 
  key = {key}, 
  volume = {28}, 
  OPTnumber = {4}, 
  pages = {307-308}, 
  OPTmonth = {month}, 
  note = {Abstract for 28th Annual Meeting of Assoc. for Symbolic Logic}, 
  OPTannote = {annote},
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Always make a small, but compilable test file.

Comment: Not the point of the question, but with `style=authoryear,` the default sorting is `sorting=nyt,`, which sorts by name-year-title and is more natural for an author-year bibliography than `sorting=nty,` which sorts by name-title-year. I'd just get rid of the `sorting=nty` in this example.

Comment: I can't see how this question survived closing about missing details: can this be useful to any future reader? The answer is a “crystal ball” one.

Comment: @egreg "I can't see how this question survived closing about missing details:" What missing details do you allude to here? "can this be useful to any future reader?" The answer is quite clear, in my opinion, and it was certainly very useful to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `key` field is an alias for `sortkey`, which influences the sorting of the entries. With `key = {key}`, all `Kriesel, G.` author entries are now sorted based on the value `key`, which comes before `Kleene, S.~C.`.

The remedy is to remove all `key` or `sortkey` fields and let the sorting occur naturally via your `sorting = nty` (the default) option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{Kleene1952, 
  author = {Kleene, S.~C.}, 
  title = {Mathematical Logic}, 
  year = {1952}, 
  publisher = {North-Holland Publishing Company}, 
}
@Article{Kreisel1963a, 
  author = {Kreisel, G.}, 
  title = {Subformula Prop. and Reflection Principles}, 
  journal = {J. Symb. Log.}, 
  year = {1963}, 
  volume = {28}, 
  OPTnumber = {4}, 
  pages = {305-306}, 
}
@Article{Kreisel1963b, 
  author = {Kreisel, G.}, 
  title = {Reflection Principle for {H}eyting's arithmetic}, 
  journal = {J. Symb. Log.}, 
  year = {1963}, 
  volume = {28}, 
  OPTnumber = {4}, 
  pages = {306-307}, 
}
@Article{Kreisel1963c, 
  author = {Kreisel, G.}, 
  title = {Reflection Principles and Omega-inconsistency}, 
  journal = {J. Symb. Log.}, 
  year = {1963}, 
  volume = {28}, 
  OPTnumber = {4}, 
  pages = {307-308}, 
}
\end{filecontents*}

\usepackage[
  backend = biber,
  style = authoryear,
  sorting = nty
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. You beat me to this answer by about 30 seconds. :-)

Comment: @Werner Many thanks!